# Jackson custom date serializer

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I need to set format for class' date serialization.
I have the version of Jackson, which doesn't have @JsonFormat. That's Why I wrote custom class:

```
public class CDJsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{

@Override
public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
    jsonGenerator.writeString(dateString);
}
```

}

And used it:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CDJsonDateSerializer.class)
private Date startDate;
```

But, I have another fields which have different date's formats and I don't want to create another classes for serialization. Can I add all needed formats like constants to CDJsonDateSerializer class and set needed format with annotation `@JsonSerialize` ?
Something like this:

`@JsonSerialize(using = CDJsonDateSerializer.class, CDJsonDateSerializer.FIRST_FORMAT)`.

**AFTER THE ANSWER BELOW:**

It works after some corrections. I've changed the way of getting annotation in **createContextual** method:

```
@Override
public JsonSerializer createContextual(SerializationConfig serializationConfig, BeanProperty beanProperty) {
    return new CustomDateSerializer(beanProperty.getAnnotation(JsonDateFormat.class).value());
}
```

And I've added **@JacksonAnnotation** to my created new annotation JsonDateFormat:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotation
public @interface JsonDateFormat {
   String value();
}
```

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037695/multiple-jackson-serializers-of-same-return-type#20128251

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you cannot use [@JsonFormat](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling) from Jackson 2, I'd recommend you to introduce your own custom annotation which will contain the format field. Your serailizer should then implement the `ContextualSerializer` interface to get access to the annotation value.

Here is an example for Jackson 1.9.X:

```
public class JacksonDateFormat {
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface MyJsonFormat {
        String value();
    }

    public static class Bean {
        @MyJsonFormat("dd.MM.yyyy") @JsonSerialize(using = MyDateSerializer.class)
        public final Date date1;

        @MyJsonFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") @JsonSerialize(using = MyDateSerializer.class)
        public final Date date2;

        public Bean(final Date date1, final Date date2) {
            this.date1 = date1;
            this.date2 = date2;
        }
    }

    public static class MyDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
            implements ContextualSerializer {
        private final String format;

        private MyDateSerializer(final String format) {this.format = format;}

        public MyDateSerializer() {this.format = null;}

        @Override
        public void serialize(
                final Date value, final JsonGenerator jgen, final SerializerProvider provider)
                throws IOException {
            jgen.writeString(new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(value));
        }

        @Override
        public JsonSerializer createContextual(
                final SerializationConfig serializationConfig, final BeanProperty beanProperty)
                throws JsonMappingException {
            final AnnotatedElement annotated = beanProperty.getMember().getAnnotated();
            return new MyDateSerializer(annotated.getAnnotation(MyJsonFormat.class).value());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final Bean value = new Bean(new Date(), new Date());
        System.out.println(mapper
                        .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                        .writeValueAsString(value));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "date1" : "02.12.2014",
  "date2" : "2014-12-02"
}
```

If you have access to the `ObjectMapper` you can register your custom serializer for all the `Date` types, so you want longer need to put `@JsonSerialize` annotation.

Here is an example:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("", Version.unknownVersion());
module.addSerializer(Date.class, new MyDateSerializer(null));
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! It's a good solution. But I use @ResponseBody and code, that in main bloc, is redundant for me. Can I serialize an object with annotation? I mean: 
@MyJsonFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
@JsonSerialize(using = MyDateSerializer.class)
private Date startDate;
Just in this case I get Exception, because MyDateSerializer waits for argument. I tried to create constructor without argument, but in this case I get NullPointer in serialize method :)

Comment: I have updated the question (AFTER THE ANSWER BELOW:). What do you think about it?

Comment: @AlexSmith Hard to say without seeing the exception stack trace. I recommend to run it under debugger to check what is wrong there.